# Disable Calling of onDraw after finish drawing android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I want to make the following :

1. get canvas
2. draw list of rectangles and bitmaps on the canvas
   based on for loop
3. after drawing all items don't call onDraw until
   I rotate the device, because the application is too slow when I try
   to navigate through it
4. My Canvas is in HorizontalScrollView

and When I try to scroll it is very slow

EDIT : I'm extending View class, so can I save the view and don't call onDraw unless I want it invalidate ??

EDIT 2 : This is my onDraw Method

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


        super.onDraw(canvas);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < mIcons.size() ; i++) {

            prepareItem(canvas, paint, mIcons.get(i));
        }

    }
```

please any one can help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround to make this work, I have draw in bitmap and every time I try to call onDraw() I check if my bitmap is not null use it

Thanks All

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent onDraw from being called but you can override it and use flag which will tell whether it should execute or not. I don't see your code but I suggest you something like:

boolean callOnDraw = true;

```
   @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);

      if(callOnDraw){
        for (int i = 0 ; i < mIcons.size() ; i++) {

            prepareItem(canvas, paint, mIcons.get(i));
        }
        callOnDraw = false;
      }

    }
```

And when you want stop drawing you set flag `callOnDraw = false;`

Comment: I have tried to add flag callOnDraw and set it with false when I finish my for loop, but what happen that it draw the canvas and then clear it

Comment: Can you show code how you did it? Because if you don't call super.onDraw(canvas); it will be not drawn.

Comment: I have added the code of onDraw method on the original post, but without the callOnDraw flag

Comment: I have tried it again with your code and I have the same behavior, it draw the canvas and then clear all the drawings and just show white screen

Comment: and if you put super.onDraw inside if(callondraw) ?

Comment: The same behavior, but it clear drawing after the first touch

Comment: try method setWillNotDraw(true)

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by calling `return;` after an if condition. Like:

```
if(lengthX == lengthTotal) return;
```